# Can the r-scale value (for Bayes Factor) be directly based on Cohen's d?

Tags: bayesian, prior, effect-size, likelihood-ratio, cohens-d

I want to set an r-scale value for a Bayesian t-test (i.e. to calculate Bayes Factor likelihood ratio) based on previous results (i.e., from a posterior). But I simply cannot find a straightforward official explanation about how to do it.

The only sensible description I found is in a blog post by D. Lakens: http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2016/01/power-analysis-for-default-bayesian-t.html

This says that the r-scale should basically have the same value as the expected Cohen's d (i.e., standardized mean difference; based on the previous result). However, I could not find support (or explanation) for this anywhere else.

I also tried it in R, and it doesn't work as I'd expect. I would imagine that if I use the original data from which I get the posterior, and give it as prior r-scale, I should get maximum BF. But in fact the peak always seems to be with a somewhat lower r-scale value.

```
library(MBESS)
library(BayesFactor)

var1 = c(9,8,6,7,8,6,5,7,8,8)
var2 = c(3,4,5,6,7,5,3,2,4,5)

ttest = t.test(var1, var2, paired=T)
ci.sm(ncp = ttest$statistic, N = length(var1), conf.level = .95)$Standardized.Mean # this gives effect size as d = 1.494293

as.vector( ttestBF(var1, var2, paired = T, rscale = 1.494293) ) # with actual effect size as r-scale, BF = 43.78086
```

However, the peak is actually when I give r-scale at around 1.30:

```
as.vector( ttestBF(var1, var2, paired = T, rscale = 1.50) ) # smaller: 43.7633
as.vector( ttestBF(var1, var2, paired = T, rscale = 1.30) ) # larger: 44.07731 
as.vector( ttestBF(var1, var2, paired = T, rscale = 1.25) ) # again smaller: 44.03929
```

So shouldn't the peak be at `rscale = 1.494293`?

Comment: This isn't an answer since I haven't totally unpacked WHY this they made this the case, but p. 233 in Rouder, et al. 2009 describes it as almost being a protection against noise. So with large rscale, what is happening is that the BF is scaled in favor of the null, so that only true large effects will tip the evidence scales.